# Can't print € symbol in console.log?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I'm pretty sure this is a very silly question but... I'm trying to output the Euro simbol (€) using `console.log` but I keep getting the following output:

> â‚¬

I'm using UTF-8 for the encoding of my HTML file and the following is my whole html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('€');
  </script>
</body>
```

Funny thing is, when I rename the file from `index.html` to `index.php`, then the `console.log` outputs the Euro symbol correctly.

What's going on here?

Comment: Hmm, it prints the correct Euro sign for me on Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: If this relates to an HTTP request, what is the HTTP response's Content-Type header value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charset declaration is missing:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`console.log('\u20AC');`